# If statement without using 'CASE'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I want to make a simple check for something and convert the answer to a bit (boolean), using SQL. An example, I want to check if something is a car, by checking the number of wheels. I could do this:

```
CASE
    WHEN NumberOfWheels > 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS 'IsCar'
```

But this only gives me the correct value, not nessesarilly the correct datatype. So I would have add a `CAST <value> AS BIT` as well.

```
CAST(
    (CASE
        WHEN NumberOfWheels > 2 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
AS BIT) 'IsCar'
```

Now this is requires two operations (`CAST` and `CASE`) rather than just one. Also it is slightly less readable. Is it possible to make the statement in a simpler way, preferably without using `CASE`. I would like something like this (which does not work):

```
CAST(NumberOfWheels > 2 AS BIT)
```

Is that even remotely possible?

Comment: This is very simple query, I don't see anything wrong with `CAST` and `CASE`. I don't think that there could be anything simpler.

Comment: Try using True and False

Comment: Btw, there are DBMSes where `NumberOfWheels > 2` in the Select list works and returns either `true` or `false` :-)

Comment: Simple as it is, it is still twice as complex as it could be (if I could do what I wanted). Regarding the choice of database provider, then it isn't something I can control.

Comment: If CAST is the problem, declare a bit and return the bit variable instead of 1 or 0

Comment: Why not just leave the value as an integer, tinyint, or character.  The effort put into make the value narrower probably will have no affect on performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. T-SQL has neither a boolean type nor typed `BIT` literals, so any way you slice it a conversion will be involved. You can still cut down on the verbiage a bit by using `IIF` rather than `CASE`, and (in my opinion) `CONVERT` makes for slightly easier reading than `CAST`, but that doesn't change the fundamentals:

```
SELECT IsCar = CONVERT(BIT, IIF(NumberOfWheels > 2, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you. At least you made it look prettier :-). Is there any difference in performance, compared to my initial suggestion?

Comment: @Noceo: None whatsoever. Internally `IIF` is rewritten into a `CASE`, so that you end up with the exact same execution plan for both expressions.